# my flutter shows the following error on the bulld gradle, line 2

Tags: flutter, build.gradle

```
[{
    "resource": "/Users/joel/bloodhope/android/app/build.gradle",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#6",
    "code": "0",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip'.\norg.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.\nA problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.\nA problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.\nA problem occurred configuring project ':app'.\nBuild file '/Users/joel/bloodhope/android/app/build.gradle' line: 2\nAn exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']\nFailed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.\nAndroid Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.\n Your current JDK is located in /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home\n You can try some of the following options:\n  - changing the IDE settings.\n  - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.\n  - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.",
    "source": "Java",
    "startLineNumber": 2,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 2,
    "endColumn": 1
}]
```

tried  updating  java

Comment: The message made it clear that you're using Java 1.8, make sure to change it and run java --version in your terminal to make sure is 11 (if using JAVA_HOME variable)